# dynamic position custom popover based on the page height

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have my ui-bootstrap-custom-0.12.1.js for popover with default position set to "top", However if the popover is at top as default I cannot view my content in popover. Is there a way to dynamic position the popover to bottom?.

```
<div class="pagination-centered">
  <h2>Title: {{item.title}}</h2>
  <div  popover="patientHover" popover-title="item.title" popover-placement="top" popover-trigger="click">
    <button class="btn">{{text}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the plunker link [Popover position top][1]

http://plnkr.co/edit/OQ9xia2dmW1tgnYzNCKD?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

the `popover-placement` tag takes a string as an argument instead of javascript. However, you can pass javascript to the tag (and thus implement some logic of your own that determines its placement) like so:

`popover-placement="{{$scope.dynamicPopoverFunction(args)}}"`

This will allow you to call a function in your scope and return the placement you desire.